# Parsley remote validate

Tags: javascript, php, validation, parsley.js

I have the following input field for username:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="username" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-remote="/User/user_exists" data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST", "dataType": "json", "data": { "request": "ajax" } }'>
```

This works fine and calls my `PhP function`:

```
public function user_exists()
{
    if($this->isAjax())
    {
        $user = $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? ', 's', array($_POST['username']), MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
        if($user != null)
        {
            print json_encode("400");
        }
        else
        {
            print json_encode("200");
        }
    }
}
```

However i am unsure what to do to either deny or allow the validation.

the documentation isnt much of help (atleast i have trouble finding it)

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, parsley.remote will consider all 2xx ajax responses as a **valid** response, and all the others as **wrong** response.

We have the same concern in our app, leveraging Parsley to tell a user if the username / email he wants is available in our database. To do so, and keep a correct REST API response (200 if user found, 404 if not), you need to tell parsley.remote to **do the opposite** of this behavior either by:

- using `data-parsley-remote-reverse="true"`
- using `data-parsley-remote-validator="reverse"` to tell to use the reverse validator (exact same thing as above)
- last but not least, create your own validator (that we did in our project) for this check:

  window.ParsleyExtend.asyncValidators['remote-email'] = function (xhr) {
      return xhr.status === 404;
  };

and use `data-parsley-remote-validator="remote-email"`

All that is explained [here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote) in the doc.

Hope that helped.

Best

Answer (score 1):

In your php file:

```
public function user_exists()
{
    if($this->isAjax())
    {
        $user = $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? ', 's',array($_POST['username']), MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
        if($user != null)
        {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 Ok");
        }
    }
}
```